# Help understanding a group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I was experimenting with various presentations for groups, and I stumbled upon $G := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [aba,b]^6 \rangle$. I found that it has order 11741184, but the magma calculator won't give me much more than that. What I would like to know is: What are the composition factors of this group? I know that PSL(2,7) is one of them (making the order of [aba,b] 3 instead of 6 gives PSL(2,7)), but other than that I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I just figured it out. The groups 
$H := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [a,b]^{28}, [aba,b]^6 \rangle$ and
$I := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [a,b]^{8}, [aba,b]^6 \rangle$ are quotients of this group, and H has composition series: PSL(2,7)-PSL(2,13), and the second has composition series PSL(2,7)-Z2^6. Therefore the whole group has composition series: PSL(2,13)-PSL(2,7)-Z2^6.

Comment: Alternatively, if you run the LowIndexSubgroups command (up to index 14 is enough) then you can quickly find quotients isomorphic to ${\rm PSL}(2,13)$ and $2^6.{\rm PSL}(2,7)$ as coset images of the subgroups of low index.

Comment: Right, of course. It is interesting, there isn't a group 2^6.PSL(2,13) (at least as a quotient of the group).

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a quotient with composition series: PSL(2,13)-PSL(2,7)-2^3?

Comment: Yes there are two such quotients. The group is a direct product of ${\rm PSL}(2,13)$ with a group with structure $2^{3+3}.{\rm PSL}(2,7)$.

Comment: Could you give a relation to add to make such a group?

Comment: $[a,b]^7$ I think

Comment: Adding $[a,b]^7$ gives ${\rm PSL}(2,13)$. Adding $(ab^{-1}abab^{-1}ababab^{-1})^3$ gives one of the $2^3.{\rm PSL}(2,7)$ images.

Comment: Ok, but what is the relation that will give the group with composition factors PSL(2,13)-PSL(2,7)-2^3?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you wanted $PSL(2,13)$. Then (this is one element) 

$ ab^{-1}ababab^{-1}ab^{-1}abab^{-1}ababab^{-1}abab^{-1}abab^{-1}$

$  ab^{-1}abab^{-1}abab^{-1}ab^{-1}abab^{-1}ab^{-1}abab^{-1}ab
$

$
ab^{-1}
  ababab^{-1}abab^{-1}abab^{-1}ab^{-1}abab^{-1}ab^{-1}abab
$

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to complete the list of quotients of this group. I now have PSL(2,13)-PSL(2,7)-2^6, PSL(2,13)-PSL(2,7)-2^3, PSL(2,13)-PSL(2,7), PSL(2,13), PSL(2,7)-2^6, PSL(2,7)-2^3, PSL(2,7), and the trivial group. Did I miss any out?

Comment: It is really surprising how many times one of the relations is redundant. For example, the added relation to make 2^3.PSL(2,7) makes the (aba,b)^6 relation redundant.